# MySQL: get the records in case of overlapping

Tags: mysql

I have the following query

```
select 
      fromDate, toDate, duration
from 
      timetable
where
     type = '06'        AND
     fromDate BETWEEN '2017-01-26 17:07:54' and  '2017-01-26 17:19:50' AND
     toDate BETWEEN '2017-01-26 17:07:54' and  '2017-01-26 17:19:50' AND
     objectId like '%Prinoth BisonX%' limit 20;
```

and I am trying to get the records even if there is an overlap with the giving intervall (fromDate and toDate). So with this  fromDate value '2017-01-26 17:07:54' and toDate '2017-01-26 17:19:50' I am getting 4 records

[image]

if I change the fromDate to '2017-01-26 17:10:00' I am getting 3 records as a result

[image]

but I want to get the fourth record as well too since there is an overlap with the intervall.How can I get it in the query?

**Edit**
This seems to me to be right!

```
select 
      fromDate, toDate, duration
from 
      timetable
where
     type = '06'              AND
       fromDate <= '2017-01-26 17:19:49'  AND
       toDate >= '2017-01-26 17:10:00' AND
        objectId like '%Prinoth BisonX%' limit 20;
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Note that Event A can be said to overlap Event B if Event A starts before Event B ends and ends after Event B starts.

Comment: @Strawberry please take a look at my edited.

Comment: I have nothing to add to my original comment